# ngu-carousel implementation with angular 7

Tags: angular, carousel, angular7

searching for a good `non-jQuery` carousel for angular i found [ngu-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngu/carousel) but trying to use it in angular 7 you might face some problems which will hopefully be dealt with in next versions but for now here are some search results i would like to share to help you speed up.

some errors you might see:

> Cannot read property 'all' of undefined ngu slider
>
> Generic type 'NguCarousel' requires 1 type argument(s)

the latest version is `1.5.4` at the time i'm posting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as in [this](https://github.com/sheikalthaf/ngu-carousel/issues/93) issue owner has provided a [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngu-carousel-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsimple%2Fsimple.component.html) which is almost working!
just change this line

```
  @ViewChild('myCarousel') myCarousel: NguCarousel;
```

to this

```
  @ViewChild('myCarousel') myCarousel: NguCarousel<any>;
```

and for `rtl` users, make sure you put the carousel in a `ltr` container